# Changing Legend content display in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to change the contents of the legend to be more realistic of the dataset.

Background: I'm doing a kmeans clustering of wine quality, the dataset has both red and white wines. While the scale is theoretically from 1 to 10, the actual dataset itself only has values from 3 to 9 inclusive.

My code:

```
set.seed(20)
wine.cluster <- kmeans(wine[12], 7) #we know that there are only values of 3 to 9 in the dataset thanks to summary data
wine.cluster$cluster <- as.factor(wine.cluster$cluster)
ggplot(wine, aes(label, alcohol, colour = wine.cluster$cluster) ) + labs(colour = "Quality", title = "Kmeans On Label and Alcohol Content") + geom_point()
```

this results in the following graph:
[Kmeans clustering on alcohol and label as Wine Quality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAeEL.png)

The problem is that all the legend items; 1 - 7 are wrong, they should be 3 - 9, and I want to change those legend items without changing the results.

Comment: Instead of editing your original post, I would encourage you to provide an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function scale_color_hue as a way to change legend elements.

To continue my example above of changing the legend elements from 1-7 inclusive, I can use:

```
ggplot(...) + labs(...) + scale_color_hue( labels = c("3","4","5","6","7","8","9") )
```